Custom error message for second code from same promotion
I am trying to add a custom error message to the case when a user tries to add a second promotion code from the same promotion. Is there any way to do that instead of decorating route /checkout/promotion/add ?
enter image description here
When I am trying to add a second promotion code the exception is lineItemNotStackable and default error message is shown: 'Ops something went wrong'

hi there, share your code as the plain text format not as an image~

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can create a new custom CartValidator instead decorating a promotion route.
pseudo-code:
class DuplicatePromotionCodeValidator implements CartValidatorInterface
{
    public function validate(Cart $cart, ErrorCollection $errors, SalesChannelContext $context): void
    {
        $promotionCodes = [];
        foreach ($cart->getLineItems()->getFlat() as $lineItem) {
            if ($lineItem->getType() === LineItem::PROMOTION_LINE_ITEM_TYPE) {
                $promotionId = $lineItem->getReferencedId();
                if (isset($promotionCodes[$promotionId])) {
                    $errors->add(new \Exception('your custom error for dup promotion here'));
                    return;
                }
                $promotionCodes[$promotionId] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

And don't forget register your custom validator in the services configuration.
Hope that can help.
